# Работа с векторами C++

Tags: c++

Получил в университете следующее задание:

> Создать 2 объекта разработанного класса. Класс – динамический вектор
>   (одномерный массив). В результате выполнения программы в первом
>   объекте должны содержаться все четные, а во втором все нечетные числа
>   исходных векторов. Содержимое объектов (их векторов) до и после обмена
>   вывести на экран.

Мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class MyVectorClass
{
private:
    const int _vecSize = 10;
    vector<int> _myVector;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
public:
    MyVectorClass()
    {
        _myVector.resize(_vecSize);
    }

    MyVectorClass(int _newVecSize)
    {
        _myVector.resize(_newVecSize);
    }

    MyVectorClass(vector<int> _copyVector)
    {
        _copyVector.resize(_vecSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < _copyVector.size(); i++)
        {
            _copyVector[i] = _myVector[i];
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> GetVector()
    {
        return _myVector;
    }

    /*int GetItemByID(int id)
     {
     return _myVector[id];
     } */

    void GenerateData(int _params)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _myVector.size(); i++)
        {

            _myVector[i] = rand() % +_params;
        }
    }

    void CompareAndSort(vector<int> _compareVector)
    {
        vector<int> _temparyVector(_vecSize * 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < _myVector.size(); i++)
        {
            _temparyVector.push_back(_myVector[i]);
            _temparyVector.push_back(_compareVector[i]);
        }

        _myVector.clear();
        _compareVector.clear();

        int _trueCount = 0;
        int _falseCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < _temparyVector.size(); i++)
        {
            if (_temparyVector[i] % 2 == 0)
                _trueCount++;
        }
        _falseCount = _temparyVector.size() - _trueCount;

        _myVector.resize(_trueCount);
        _compareVector.resize(_falseCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < _temparyVector.size(); i++)
            if (_temparyVector[i] % 2 == 0)
                _myVector.push_back(_temparyVector[i]);
            else
                _compareVector.push_back(_temparyVector[i]);
    }
};

void CoutVectorData(vector<int> _targetVector)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _targetVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << _targetVector[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << " " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    MyVectorClass vec1;
    MyVectorClass vec2;

    vec1.GenerateData(100);
    vec2.GenerateData(100);

    cout << "First vector: ";
    CoutVectorData(vec1.GetVector());
    cout << "Second vector: ";
    CoutVectorData(vec2.GetVector());

    cout << "Compare and sort divided by 2:" << endl;
    vec1.CompareAndSort(vec2.GetVector());

    cout << "First vector: ";
    CoutVectorData(vec1.GetVector());
    cout << "Second vector: ";
    CoutVectorData(vec2.GetVector());

    cout << "Say hello to cpp:";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Код далек от порядочного, прошу меня простить.
Вопрос таков : В функции **CompareAndSort** почему в **_compareVector** остаются четные значения элементов **после** проверки?

Так же, почему **_temparyVector** создается с 40(!) элементами вместо 20 (_vecsize *2)?

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На вскидку - вызываете метод .resize(), а затем делаете push_back() - в итоге - элементов больше, чем предполагалось.

Comment: temparyvector не содержит метода resize в коде

Comment: Да я Вам на общие недостатки указываю. А вот c _myVector Вы это проделываете. И в цикле Вы 20 раз делаете вот это: ```_temparyVector.push_back(_myVector[i]);
        _temparyVector.push_back(_compareVector[i]);```

Comment: Так же попрошу обратить внимание на код 3 конструктора, и на то, что нужно научиться пользовать ссылками ))

Comment: @crystal  У вас задание - создать класс динамического вектора. Это  означает, что никаких стандартных контейнеров типа std::vector вы в своем классе использовать не должны. Так что ваше решение изначально не верное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас изначально неверное решение. В вашем задании сказано

> Класс – динамический вектор (одномерный массив).

А это означает, что ваш класс должен самостоятельно выделять динамически память под массив, изменять его размер и удалять выделенную память.

Вас не просят создать оболочку вокруг стандартного контейнера `std::vector`, так как такая задача не имеет смысла, так как можно изначально использовать этот стандартный контейнер без всяких оболочек в виде динамического массива. А вас просят создать некоторый упрощенный аналог класса `std::vector`. Это совершенно разные задачи.

Это задание на проверку умения работать с динамической памятью, а не на работу со стандартным классом `std::vector`.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Буду переделывать, в таком случае. Спасибо!

Comment: @crystal Главное - это напишите в явном виде корректно конструктор копирования, оператор присваивания и деструктор.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, второй вопрос совсем простой...

```
    vector<int> _temparyVector(_vecSize * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < _myVector.size(); i++)
    {
        _temparyVector.push_back(_myVector[i]);
        _temparyVector.push_back(_compareVector[i]);
    }
```

Вы создаете вектор с `_vecSize * 2` элементами, а потом еще **добавляете** в него `2*_myVector.size()` элементов...

Что касается `_compareVector`, то вы передаете его в функцию **по значению**,

```
void CompareAndSort(vector<int> _compareVector)
```

а значит все, что вы делаете в функции **с копией**, совершенно никак не влияет на исходный вектор... Вот в нем и остается все, что было до вызова.

Comment: Спасибо за решение проблемы. К сожалению уже не актуально. Ну хоть знаю теперь хоть что-то о векторах. Как-то не няшно писать на цпп после шарпа :c